# Clone Hard Drive and upload/use in Azure, AWS or Google Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, cloud, disk, dd

I have a server which I'd like to move to a cloud service. Now to make sure everything works as on the old, I would like to dd if=/dev/sda | ssh root@serverB "dd bs=16M of=/home/root/hdd.iso"

Now i thought it would be easy to upload the hdd.iso to azure to create a /dev/sda thats the same as my old server. But i cant find anything on how to do it. When I create a disk in Azure, the only options are Snapshot or Blob Storage, but I dont know how to go from .iso to those.

Is there a way to do this how I planned?

Comment: you can refer to this for migrating physical servers to azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/tutorial-migrate-physical-virtual-machines

Comment: When going that way and I try to install the MobSvcInstaller, I will get this error: My kernel and OS is supported, Ubuntu 16.04, but the installer stilll has a problem.{
        "Errors":
        [
                {
                        "error_name":"ASRMobilityServiceBootDiskNotFound",
                        "error_params":{},
                        "default_message":"The boot disk is not available. Create a bootable partition."
                }
        ]
}